# Compare numbers through a loop to set a status accordingly

Tags: php, symfony

Let me change my question completely to explain myself better;

I have an order;

[image]

An order have multiple order rows. Each order row has two fields; Quantity ordered, and quantity delivered.

If **all** order rows' quantities delivered are the same as the quantity ordered, the entire order should get a status of '100% delivered'.

If multiple or even one order row's quantities delivered **does not match** the quantities ordered the entire order should get a status of 'partly delivered'.

If no order row have any deliveries (**if all deliveries stands on 0**) the status should be '0% delivered'.

What I have so far looks only at the last order row of the entire order because all the previous rows gets overridden by the latest check. This is my code;

```
public function deliveryAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $order = $em->getRepository('QiBssBaseBundle:PmodOrder')->find($id);

    $orderRowsDelivered = $request->request->all();

    $delivered = "0%";

    foreach ($orderRowsDelivered['order_row_id'] as $orderRowId => $quantityDelivered) {
        if($quantityDelivered != '' || $quantityDelivered != null) {
            $orderRow = $em->getRepository("QiBssBaseBundle:PmodOrderRow")->find($orderRowId);

            $orderDelivered = new PmodDelivery();

            $orderDelivered->setOrderRow($orderRow);
            $orderDelivered->setQuantity($quantityDelivered);
            $orderDelivered->setTimeArrived(new \DateTime());

            $em->persist($orderDelivered);
            $em->flush();

            if($orderRow->getQuantityDelivered() > 0 && $orderRow->getQuantityDelivered() < $orderRow->getQuantity()) {
                $delivered = "partly";
            } elseif ($orderRow->getQuantityDelivered() == $orderRow->getQuantity()) {
                $delivered = "100%";
            }                
        }
    }

    var_dump($delivered);exit;

    return new RedirectResponse ... ;
}
```

Because as of this moment he looks at the last one with 10 and 8 in the example image, and give a status of 'partly', as soon as the 'quantity delivered' amounts is entered. But he should take all rows together.

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: You should tell what's not working, what results are different from what you expect?

Comment: Not clear at all about the order. Give full details. Do you compare different people order or one person order many times?

Comment: Side note, do you actually need this status persisted? I mean, the value could simply be aggregated *on demand*. Also, I'm not sure about your orm mapping, it seems you do some of the work doctrine would normally do for you, *by hand*. It all looks a bit strange.

Comment: @Yoshi I need the status. Don't worry about how strange this looks to you, therefore you need to understand the entire project. But that is not the problem. All I need is to update an order status depending on what the mentioned numbers are. Keep it to the topic

Comment: Well then the answer is quite simple. Only sum up all quantities inside the loop, and do the test regarding those quantities (resulting in the status you need) **after** the loop. Currently the last `$orderRow` defines this status.

Comment: You have to take an array of $delivered. In above code each time $delivered value overwrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what Cerad in the comments of his own answer said, this is my answer; (I'll make use of OP's scenario where he uses order rows per order.)

I've added an extra property to my **OrderRow entity** called `$rowStatus`.

After that I created a getter function for the `$rowStatus` called `getRowStatus()` that gives each row a status individually;

```
public function getRowStatus()
{
    if ($this->getQuantityDelivered() == $this->getQuantity()) {
        return $this->rowStatus = 100;
    } elseif ($this->getQuantityDelivered() == 0) {
        return $this->rowStatus = 0;
    } else {
        return $this->rowStatus = 50;
    }
}
```

After that in my **Order entity** I've added a `$deliveryStatus` property, with a corresponding getter function called `getDeliveryStatus()` that looks like this;

```
public function getDeliveryStatus()
{
    if (count($this->getOrderRows()) > 0) {    //this check is to make sure there are orderRows, because you can't devide by zero if it might happen that there are no order rows. If not the delivery status will just be set on 0.
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($this->getOrderRows() as $row) {
            $sum += $row->getRowStatus();
        }
        $average = $sum / count($this->getOrderRows());

        if ($average == 100) {
            return $this->deliveryStatus = 100;
        } elseif ($average == 0) {
            return $this->deliveryStatus = 0;
        } else {
            return $this->deliveryStatus = 50;
        }
    } else {
        return $this->deliveryStatus = 0;
    }
}
```

That's it! After this I just use an enum function to display the 100 as "100% delivered", the 50 as "partly delivered", and the 0 as "0% delivered". I know this isn't really necessary, and you can instead change the status number directly to a string or whatever you want to display.

Comment: Looks much cleaner.  Just be aware that average is a floating point so, depending on rounding, you might get something like 99.999 instead of 100.0.  Might be better to use if (abs($average - 100.0) < .1) { 100%!

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head I might do:

```
$deliveredNone = true;
$deliveredAll = true;
$deliveredSome = false;

foreach ($orderRowsDelivered['order_row_id'] as $orderRowId => $quantityDelivered) {

    if ($quantityDelivered) {
        $deliveredNone = false; // Know that something has been delivered
    }
    ...
    if ($orderRow->getQuantityDelivered() != $orderRow->getQuantity()) {
        $deliveredSome = true;
        $deliveredAll = false;
    }
}
$delivered = null;
if ($deliveredNone) $delivered = '0%';
if ($deliveredAll)  $delivered = '100%';
if ($deliveredSome) $delivered = 'partly';
```

Though I would probably just update the order with the quantities delivered then use a different function to calculate the percentage delivered.  As you can see, mixing the two processes can result in confusion.

Comment: Cerad, I have a very similar issue, and I just can't wrap my head around it. I've implemented your sample, and it works nicely up to a point. If just one of the rows' values are the same, the `$delivered` variable is immediately set to 100% even some other rows are not completed yet, so the value should remain on partly. Can you please assist some more?

Comment: @Mentos93  I wrote this answer more out of boredom that anything else.  Was pretty sure it was going to be a drive by question.  Don't try to follow this code.  Instead, update the database with the products delivered then do a second query to determine the percent remaining.  Trying to do both at the same time will lead to silly code like what I posted.  And even if you got it to work, it would almost impossible to maintain.  Imagine coming back after a few months and trying to figure out what was going on.

Comment: Cerad, see my answer to see what I've come up with. What do you think?